# dhtmlx date format in server side is not working

Tags: java, dhtmlx

In client side:

```
{type: "calendar", name: "podatet", label: "PO Date To", value: "", dateFormat: "%d-%m-%Y", calendarPosition: "right","skin":"omega",inputWidth:200},
```

In server side :

```
"Wed Dec 05 2012 10:31:00 GMT 0530 (India Standard Time)"
```

but I want dd/mm/yyyy, why it comes like this even I formatted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form api allows to access both data as object and date as string. 
If you are using

```
myForm.getFormData()
```

you will get date object, which will look as above string on server side. 
But if you will use

```
myForm.getFormData(true)
```

form will return string formatted according to the dateFormat mask