# dhtmlx date format in server side doesn't work

Tags: javascript, dhtmlx

In js:

```
   {
        type: "calendar",
        serverDateFormat: "%d-%m-%Y",
        dateFormat: "%d-%m-%Y",
        name: "al_date_to",
        label: "Date To",
        readonly: true,
        validate: "NotEmpty",
        value: "",
        calendarPosition: "right"
    },
```

In server side is :

```
"Fri Dec 21 09:40:00 UTC+0800 2012"
```

I want to the date format is d-m-yyyy, I don't know how to solve this problem. I saw this page , but I don't know how to use.[dhtmlx date format in server side is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13677474/dhtmlx-date-format-in-server-side-is-not-working).
Could you help me please.

Comment: Do you have a `getFormData()` in your client side code?

Comment: I don't know how to use getFormData(). Could you give me the suggestion.

Comment: I'm not well acquainted with dhtmlx, and you did not post any of your client side code except for the one object.  Which makes it hard to identify the problem.

Comment: I think i saw the answer to the same question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13677474/dhtmlx-date-format-in-server-side-is-not-working